# Matrix triangulation over $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: linear-algebra

If I have a matrix $A$ and all eigenvalues of $A$ are complex numbers can I conclude that the matrix isn't triangulable over $\mathbb{R}$? If not, how can I prove that $A$ isn't triangulable over $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Technically, real numbers *are* complex numbers. In practice, you can even weaken the hypothesis: if a real matrix has at least one (hence at least two) eigenvalue(s) in $\Bbb C\setminus\Bbb R$, then it is not triangulable over $\Bbb R$.

Comment: You are right... sorry, the eigenvalues are purely imaginary, they are $i$ and $-i$

Answer (score 1):

The characteristic polynomial of a real $n  \times n$ triangular matrix is $p(x) = (x- a_1) \dots (x-a_n)$, where the $a_i$ are the elements in its diagonal. In particular, it has $n$ real eigenvalues, counted with multiplicity, and therefore has no purely imaginary eigenvalues.

Then, if $A$ were similar to a triangular matrix, the same would apply to it (why?), and it wouldn't have any purely imaginary eigenvalues.

Comment: Because the charcteristic polinomial of A and the triangular matrix would be the same.... thank you!